# Editing a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Very much a newbie question but I am finding myself stuck at what looks like it should be a simple task. What I'm trying to do is edit individual elements in a 2d array. Kinda like changing values on a table.

I've been trying to call a method, if a certain input is called, which will change one of the array elements. Such as change colour red to blue. If that makes any sense? Any suggestions?

Here's the code: I've shortened the code as the array is rather long

```
package gameOne;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class grid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] tableSquare = new String [15][7];

        String output = "";
        String columnAsString;
        char column;
                //first row
                tableSquare[0][0] = "      A       ";
                tableSquare[0][1] = "B       ";
        columnA(tableSquare);

        columnAsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output +"\n\nPlease enter a column", "Connect", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        column = columnAsString.charAt(0);

    }// end of main

    static void columnA(String[][] tableSquare) {
         tableSquare [12][1] = "|  red ";
    }

}//end of class
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Java does not actually have two-dimensional arrays. It has arrays of arrays (Jagged Arrays) however

Comment: post your code please?

Comment: @AluanHaddad you can call an array of arrays a 2d there's np in that, in fact most of the developers does! just to remove the confusion of whether it's an array of 2 or 2 or 3 arrays etc..

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie not sure where you got that from but if you program in a language that does not have 2D Arrays, you can pretend I guess.